# How do i script an excel action outside the application, i need to run Data-->Refresh All

Tags: excel, powershell, sharepoint, scripting

I have an excel sheet that I need to update via command line.  I am completely new to this so take it easy.  I am using an application called Alteryx to do data preparation on a excel file, but I need update the excel.iqy file from the command line.  Is there a way o run "excel.exe /options" that will update it?  The excel file is linked to a SharePoint list and I need to update the file.  My company does not allow applications to connect to SharePoint lists.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here.  Do you have a script?  Check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on writing a good question.

Comment: close the sheet and then re-open?